# When removing from array the wrong child component is removed

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, array

Sorry I wasn't sure how to phrase the title of this question.

I have a `parent` component which populates an array `cartItems` populated with objects.

For each object in the `cartItems` array a new `cartRowItem` component is created with a removal button. Clicking the button should remove the `cartItem` from the array and then cease to display the component.

With 2 object in `cartItems` I will get 2 components. If I select remove on the 1st component both components will stop displaying but the array will still contain the object for the 1st component. This is wrong - the 1st component should stop displaying and it's object should be removed from `cartItems`.

If I first remove the 2nd component then it works as expected.

parent.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-3" title="Product Cart">
        <template for:each={cartItems} for:item="item">
            <c-cart-row-item key={item.id} cart-item={item} cart-items={cartItems} oncartitemremove={handleRemove}></c-cart-row-item>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

parent.js

```
export default class TechDocSelfServe extends LightningElement {

    @api cartItems = [];

    addToCart(event) {
        const row = event.detail.row;
        this.cartItems = [...this.cartItems, row];
    
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent("cartitemadd", {
            detail: this.cartItems
        });

        console.log('cartItems on add -> ' + JSON.stringify(this.cartItems, null, 4));

        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }

    handleRemove(event) {
        this.cartItems = event.detail
    }
}
```

cartRowItem.html

```
<template>
    <template if:true={displayRow}>
        <lightning-card title={cartItem.name}>
            <lightning-button variant="destructive" label="Remove" title="Remove" 
            onclick={handleRemove} value={cartItem}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-card>    
    </template>
</template>
```

cartRowItem.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';

export default class CartRowItem extends LightningElement {

    @api cartItem;
    _cartItems;
    displayRow = true;

    @api 
    get cartItems() {
        return this._cartItems;
    }

    set cartItems(value){
        this._cartItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));
    }

    handleRemove(event) {
        var array = this._cartItems;
        var key = event.target.value.Id;
        var index = array.findIndex(function(item, i) {
            return item.Id === key
        });

        array.splice(index, 1);
        this._cartItems = array;

        console.log('cartItems after remove -> ' + JSON.stringify(this._cartItems, null, 4));
        
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent("cartitemremove", {
            detail: this._cartItems
        });

        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
        this.displayRow = false;
    }
}
```

Essentially any time I remove a `cartRowItem` I would like it's associated `cartItem` to be removed from the `cartItems` array in the parent component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child component shouldn't be trying to remove the item; this is the parent's responsibility. The child should notify of removal:

```
handleRemove(event) {
  this.dispatchEvent(
    new CustomEvent('remove', { detail: { id: event.target.value.id } })
  );
}
```

And the parent should remove the data:

```
handleRemove(event) {
  const cartId = event.detail.id;
  const index = this.cartItems.findIndex(item => item.id === cartId);
  this.cartItems.splice(index, 1);
  // If using @track, you don't need this line
  this.cartItems = [...this.cartItems];
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was thinking to update cartItems and then feed back to parent but your solution works. The only problem I have now is on the remaining data the component is removed from view. Somehow when removing item 1 then displayRow on item 2 is set to false.

Comment: resolved by removing displayRow. Thanks to sfdcfox there is no need for displayRow any more.